# SQLite trigger event not working

Tags: java, javafx, sqlite

My trigger code not working when I added it to my program, it's giving error and will not connect to database.

The following code I suspected to be causing the problem because, other insertion queries were working fine before I added the trigger query.

```
public class Connect_db {

    Connection con;
    public static Statement st = null;

    public static Connection connectdb(){
       try{

           Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
           Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:eGiftCard.db","","");
           st=con.createStatement();
           st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SetUpReward(Number INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \n"
                   + "min_Value DOUBLE (18, 2), \n"
                   + "max_Value DOUBLE (18, 2), \n"
                   + "reward_Point FLOAT, \n"
                   + "card_Length INTEGER, \n"
                   + "PayPal_Email TEXT, \n"
                   + "Bank_Name TEXT, \n"
                   + "Bank_Account TEXT)");

}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database ()
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:369)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB._exec(NestedDB.java:156)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:132)
    at database_files.Connect_db.connectdb(Connect_db.java:56)
    at view_controller.IGisftCardController.initialize(IGisftCardController.java:230
```

Comment: @halfer did you just? oh thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS eGiftCard.audit_log ...
INSERT INTO eGiftCard.ActivateAudit ...
```

The database name is not `eGiftCard` but `main`.
The database name is *not* the same as the file name.

There is no reason to use a database name here; just drop the `eGiftCard.`.

Furthermore, the trigger's `END;` is missing.

Comment: The database me is eGiftCard. besides even if i remove the database name it will still gives the same error as i have tested it before.

Comment: Help me sir. the error still showing up after removing eGiftcard. But this aqual code worked when i copy it in a text file and run it.

Comment: There is a second syntax error. And the actual error message is missing; try `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: I have fixed it. i mispelled the ActivateCard and also no END function

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.